# Python не хочет менять папку установки модуля

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Я новичек в питоне. Нужно установить модуль PySimpleGUI, запускаю установку через pip в открытом терминале проекта, но питон устанавливает его не в папку проекта, а в папку самого питона и в самом проекте выдает ошибку No module named 'PySimpleGUI' т.е. не видит его там где он ему нужен.
При попытке снова установить выдает сообщение Requirement already satisfied: PySimpleGUI in c:\users\igor\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (4.60.1)
Т.е. переустанавливать не хочет, говорит что он уже есть в другой папке. Удалял модуль в ручную, при следующей установки все равно устанавливает в ту же папку программы, а не проекта. При этом проверкой pip freeze он показывает что PySimpleGUI находится в проекте, но по факту не видит его. Не знаю что делать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать виртуальное окружение с помощью команды venv, чтобы не использовать pip для глобальной установки пакетов.  Зайдите в каталог проекта и в терминале наберите команду:
python –m venv my_venv
Создав окружение его необходимо активировать:
my_venv\Scripts\activate.bat
Проверить успешность активации можно по приглашению оболочки, в начале будет (my_venv).
Далее устанавливайте любые пакеты и работайте в изолированной среде.